# How to not display number as exponent?

Tags: r

I see a lot of articles about how to change the decimal precision in R. But is there some way to get R to display a whole number instead of showing something like `9e+08`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I see you've been given a `format` approach. Do realize that function returns a "character" value. If you wanted to globally change the behavior of your console session in favor of "whole numbers", then changing scipen `option()` is the way to go.

```
> options("scipen" = 10)
> options()$scipen
[1] 10
> 9e+08
[1] 900000000
```

The value given to 'scipen' is not actually the threshold for exponent format but is rather a "bias" with larger positive numbers increasing the values printed in fixed notation.

Comment: okay thanks. I thought the scipen option only dealt with decimal places

Comment: @Ellipsis...: you may be confusing that with the "digits" option.

Answer (score 18):

Try `format(9e+08,scientific=FALSE)`.

Comment: This will work, but remember that you get a character representation of the number, not the number itself.

Comment: I have had the similar issue, as.integer(object) worked when the class of the object integer64