# How to display numbers in a human readable format?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number format, writing 1e-5 instead of 0.00001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978266/number-format-writing-1e-5-instead-of-0-00001)
>   [How to not display number as exponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810001/how-to-not-display-number-as-exponent)

I am using RStudio and have a problem that I could not find any solution for:

When working with very large numbers, R displays those number in a shorter format.

But when calculating (for example) *(2000x1000x2000)*, I really want to see *4000000000* and **not** *4e+09*. 
How can I change that behaviour?

Comment: use `format()` to do this, or set `options(scipen= ...)`

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I'm using scipen with a pretty high value now.

Comment: I think my dupe is more precise than @MatthewPlourde's because it's about display *in R* rather than about formatting with `write.table` (although his answer does mention `scipen` as well)

Comment: @BenBolker, you're right, I should have read it more closely.

Comment: Agreed, this is a duplicate. But I was not able to find the other one as I did not search for "How not to display as exponent". We'd need a title that one can actually get the idea to search for. I usually search for a "How to" not for a "How not to" ;)

Comment: That said, my "human readable format" is likely not the best solution, either. I'd be happy for suggestions.