# Convert "(3e+04,3.5e+04]" type to number in r

Tags: r, formatting

I have data set of car speed on a road, and the distance of the car from the start point of measuring.

I wanted to check what is the mean and se in each 5 KM down the road, so I sorted the data by 'DistanceFromStart' and made a table using a function I build:

```
speedByKM <- function(testFile){
     setDT(a1a2011)[, list(Speed=mean(Speed)), by=list(cut(DistanceFromStart,breaks= seq(0, max(DistanceFromStart)+5000, by = 5000),include.lowest=TRUE))]->res
    setDT(a1a2011)[, list(Speed=se(Speed)), by=list(cut(DistanceFromStart,breaks= seq(0, max(DistanceFromStart)+5000, by = 5000),include.lowest=TRUE))]->res1
    res$se = res1$Speed 
       return(res)
 }
```

The table I got is:

```
            cut    Speed         se
1: (3e+04,3.5e+04] 88.16993 0.04784163

2:   (5e+03,1e+04] 94.33507 0.02121293

3: (2e+04,2.5e+04] 99.26032 0.03680951

4: (2.5e+04,3e+04] 90.31163 0.03991980

5:       [0,5e+03] 94.69139 0.01872111

6: (1e+04,1.5e+04] 94.70515 0.02661366

7: (1.5e+04,2e+04] 97.34650 0.02880336
```

How can I make the KM show as a number?
for example, instead of '5e+03' to show 5000? 
Thank you.

Comment: This post I think answers your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810001/how-to-not-display-number-as-exponent

Answer (score 2):

Increase the `dig.lab` parameter from its default of 3:

```
x <- (1:5) * 1e3

cut(x, c(500, 2500, 5000))
#[1] (500,2.5e+03]   (500,2.5e+03]   (2.5e+03,5e+03] (2.5e+03,5e+03] (2.5e+03,5e+03]
#Levels: (500,2.5e+03] (2.5e+03,5e+03]
cut(x, c(500, 2500, 5000), dig.lab = 4L)
#[1] (500,2500]  (500,2500]  (2500,5000] (2500,5000] (2500,5000]
#Levels: (500,2500] (2500,5000]
```